# How can you tighten a potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer, repair

I have an arcade cabinet with a broken volume control daughterboard. Soldered in is a potentiometer which turns clockwise/anticlockwise fine, but also lifts 1mm off the board. It works as intended were I to push the potentiometer dial in, but it springs back on release, breaking connection again.

I'm naive when it comes to electronics but I imagine it's just a matter of tightening the pot or pot dial so it remains closer to the board, then my problem is solved. But I can't figure out by looking at it how to accomplish this. I've never soldered (nor own an iron) so it would be an undertaking to replace the pot, especially if it's a trivial repair. But is it?

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/FmmR3rR.mp4) is a video of the potentiometer, showing I can push it in a wee bit. When pushed in, it works fine.

Comment: the motion in the video is too fast to be completely clear as to what is happening ... looks like it is not lifting off the board

Comment: @jstola maybe my wording was poor. The potentiometer sits flush with the board, but the dial can be pushed in about 1mm into the potentiometer. There's some "squish" to it when I would assume it should only turn, not be able to push in or pull out.

Comment: The larger type of potentiometer, like it sounds like you're using, are usually intended to be panel-mounted, that is, put through a hole in a panel and screwed down to hold in place. I've found that mounting them through a PCB (effectively using the PCB as the panel) is a decent way of holding them in place in a professional-looking manner, without needing to go with a full enclosure with custom mounting holes for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pot looks like it is held together by the little fingers on the metal frame that are bent over to hold the guts of the pot in place. The fingers get bent back out over time loosening the pot. You may be able to use a pair of needle nosed pliers to crimp them back down, you may have to unsolder it from the board to be able to get to them good enough. You just have to gently squeeze them down again, don't be too aggressive with it.

Comment: The video the OP placed the link to in the question shows a pot that has a construction much different from what you are trying to describe. Your description is closer to something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'm thinking it's something more like this. https://www.mouser.com/images/bourns/lrg/PTV09A_4_series_DSL.jpg

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a generic very inexpensive type of potentiometer (9mm?)- I would simply replace it with a new one of the correct size, value and taper.

You might want to get some help desoldering the existing pot if you don’t have good tools and the related skills because it is easy to damage the plated-through holes in the board. Often it helps to carefully cut the legs off before trying to remove them and clean the holes.